# Show all numbers at prime indexes in a list - haskell - filter error

Tags: list, haskell, fibonacci

This is for a class
We're supposed to write 3 functions :

1 : Prints list of fibbonaci numbers
2 : Prints list of prime numbers
3 : Prints list of fibonacci numbers whose indexes are prime

EG : Let this be fibbonaci series

Then In partC - certain elements are only shown

1: 1

*2: 1 (shown as index 2 is prime )

*3: 2  (shown as index 3 is prime )

4: 3

*5: 5 (shown )

6: 8

*7: 13  (shown as index 7 prime and so on)

I'm done with part 1 & 2 but I'm struggling with part 3. I created a function listNum that creates a sort of mapping [Integer, Integer] from the Fibbonaci series - where 1st Int is the index and 2nd int is the actual fibbonaci numbers.

Now my function partC is trying to stitch snd elements of the fibonaci series by filtering the indexes but I'm doing something wrong in the filter step.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm a beginner to Haskell.
Thanks!

```
   fib :: [Integer]
   fib = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)

   listNum :: [(Integer, Integer)]
   listNum = zip [1 .. ] fib

   primes :: [Integer]
   primes = sieve (2 : [3,5 ..])

        where
            sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x | x <- xs , x `mod` p > 0]

   partC :: [Integer]  -- Problem in filter part of this function
   partC = map snd listNum $ filter (\x -> x `elem` primes) [1,2 ..]

   main = do
      print (take 10 fib)    -- Works fine
      print (take 10 primes) --works fine
      print (take 10 listNum) --works fine
      print ( take 10 partC) -- Causes error
```

Error :

```
prog0.hs:14:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer] -> [Integer]’
              with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
     but its type ‘[Integer]’ has none
     In the expression:
    map snd listNum $ filter (\ x -> x `elem` primes) [1, 2 .. ]
  In an equation for ‘partC’:
      partC
        = map snd listNum $ filter (\ x -> x `elem` primes) [1, 2 .. ]



  |
    14 | partC = map snd listNum $ filter (\x -> x `elem` primes) [1,2 ..]
```

Comment: "Causes error" should include the actual error message.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson done

Comment: What is the meaning of ``map snd listNum $ filter (\x -> x `elem` primes) [1,2 ..]`` supposed to be?

Comment: I was trying to say filter using the indexes which will be [1, 2 .. ] ( so as to get those indexes that are prime or in the list of primes)                              and once done stitch map snd ( i.e. second ) elements - so the actual fibbonaci elements - into a single list and return that @FyodorSoikin

Comment: How long does it take to work out `elem 4 primes`?

Comment: The `$` operator is not for stitching lists. Use `++` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you intended as the original logic of `partC`. You got the syntax mostly right, but the logic has a flaw.

```
partC = snd <$> filter ((`elem` primes) . fst) (zip [1..] fib)
-- note that (<$>) = fmap = map, just infix
-- list comprehension
partC = [fn | (idx, fn) <- zip [1..] fib, idx `elem` primes]
```

But this cannot work. As @DanRobertson notes, you'll try to check `` 4 `elem` primes `` and run into an infinite loop, because `primes` is infinite and `elem` tries to be *really sure* that `4` isn't an element before giving up. We humans know that `4` isn't an element of `primes`, but `elem` doesn't.

There are two ways out. We can write a custom version of `elem` that gives up once it finds an element larger than the one we're looking for:

```
sortedElem :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Bool
sortedElem x (h:tl) = case x `compare` h of
                           LT -> False
                           EQ -> True
                           GT -> sortedElem x tl
sortedElem _ [] = False
-- or
sortedElem x = foldr (\h tl -> case x `compare` h of
                                    LT -> False
                                    EQ -> True
                                    GT -> tl
                     ) False
```

Since `primes` is a sorted list, `sortedElem` will always give the correct answer now:

```
partC = snd <$> filter ((`sortedElem` primes) . fst) (zip [1..] fib)
```

However, there is a performance issue, because every call to `sortedElem` has to start at the very beginning of `primes` and walk all the way down until it figures out whether or not the index is right. This leads into the second way:

```
partC = go primeDiffs fib
  where primeDiffs = zipWith (-) primes (1:primes)
     -- primeDiffs = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, ...]
     -- The distance from one prime (incl. 1) to the next
        go (step:steps) xs = x:go steps xs'
          where xs'@(x:_) = drop step xs
        go [] _ = [] -- unused here
     -- in real code you might pull this out into an atOrderedIndices :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
```

We transform the list of indices (`primes`) into a list of offsets, each one building on the next, and we call it `primeDiffs`. We then define `go` to take such a list of offsets and extract elements from another list. It first `drop`s the elements being skipped, and then puts the top element into the result before building the rest of the list. Under `-O2`, on my machine, this version is twice as fast as the other one when finding `partC !! 5000`.